# How can I quickly enter editing mode of a selected text layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, shortcuts

I'm looking to solve a workflow issue; editing a selected layer's text without having to go back to the mouse each time. You can change the selected layer via keyboard shortcuts, so if you could also enter editing mode through the keyboard you could quickly shift through items to edit them.

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or alternative method) that can be used to quickly enter text editing mode of a selected text layer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop - Keyboard shortcut for entering text editing mode?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104765/photoshop-keyboard-shortcut-for-entering-text-editing-mode)

Comment: Duplicate - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/104765/107891

Answer (score 10):

**Double-click the thumbnail icon for the text layer.** This will highlight the text for editing.

I think that's about as close to a shortcut as you'll get.

Answer (score 4):

Only shortcut I know of is:

1. Select your text layer
2. Press <kbd>T</kbd>
3. Click on the text object you want to edit

Comment: that's about it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a shortcut to do this. You could possibly create a [custom shortcut](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/custom-keyboard-shortcuts/) for it though. It definitely would be useful, as of now I just double click the text icon and hit <kbd>Ctrl / Option</kbd> > <kbd>Enter / Return</kbd> when I'm done to exit editing mode.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to popup the edit text window is: <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, after that for each effects on the text edit window there are shortcuts available. Please refer the below link. Hope it will helpful.

http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Photoshop_CS5.html
and 
https://www.photoshopgurus.com/forum/quick-tips-and-techniques/27266-photoshop-keyboard-shortcuts-text-typography.html

Answer (score 1):

Just select the " T " on the toolbar on your left and click on top of the text you want to EDIT! Edit it click check-mark on top and move to the next text, this way you don't even need to go on finding the layers etc...

Much easier than all other suggestions :P
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To edit the text of a selected layer without having to move the mouse back each time:

1. Have the Text Layer selected in the Layers panel (`F7`).
2. Press `Ctrl + Enter` to enter edit mode.
3. Edit your text as you like.
4. Finish by pressing `Ctrl + Enter` to exit edit mode.

Comment: You're receiving downvotes because of how short your answer is and not explaining it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea... has its downfalls though...

Edit the text you wish in one text area.
Hit control + s to save.

It will exit that text and you can then click the next with text tool.

Obviously its not perfect but most of the time when I am editing multiple text blocks this works.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I've discovered that the contextual menu for the Type tool has as the first item "Edit Type…", but I've no clue how to either invoke that menu via keyboard shortcuts or assign a keyboard shortcut to that menu item.

Answer (score -3):

1.go to text layer.
       2.press ctrl+t
       3.you can able to edit,move,resize

Comment: Hi Rajan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please explain a bit more? The Asker asked for a method that doesn't involve the mouse, but I don't see that in your solution. Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!