# Photoshop - Keyboard shortcut for entering text editing mode?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut for entering text editing mode for selected text layer without clicking or double-clicking with the mouse?

This can be duplicate, but no duplicated question answered it correctly.

Comment: Right, I have written that in details above.

Comment: CTRL+T (I think Command+T on Mac)

Comment: @BillyKerr It switches to 'type tool' but do not make selected layer enter editing mode.

Comment: @usr2564301Yes it is, but that question does not solve my problem. If you keep making as duplicate, quite possible after 5-8 years people only come here read answers, more like help documented knowledge base website.

Comment: @MohdFaizan - you're right. CTRL+T is transform. My apologies. I don't think there is a shortcut, as far as I know you have to  use the Text tool and click on the text, or double click the layer in the layers panel.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Thanks, but I doubt there must be a one.

Comment: After looking into it, I don't think it's possible (I went through all the keyboard shortcuts settings in PS, there may be some other method though) Related, and *possibly* helpful [linky](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1106135) (Note, the correct answer there *didn't** work, but maybe you'll read through it and get some ideas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I quickly enter editing mode of a selected text layer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/how-can-i-quickly-enter-editing-mode-of-a-selected-text-layer)

Comment: Yes, it is, but that duplicate does not answer the question, no point to refer to that question

Comment: @MohdFaizan its kind of irrelevant if a duplicate is not answering the question. Its still a duplicate, but its not really that easy though.

Comment: @joojaa I thoroughly disagree with you. Technology shift very rapidly, new features added every next day, old becomes obsolete. Nobody is going add or update answers to a 5-year-old question with respect to new features and updates.  

I believe every question over StackExchange should be repeated in every two years so that people won't miss the benefit of latest updates. Else the people like you find the match with a 10-decade-old question and immediately and unknowingly mark it as a duplicate!

Comment: When you answer a question it pops up into life. Stackexchange is not a forum, it is a living FAQ it is supposed to have only one question and one set of answers so that people looking for the answer have only one place to go. There are lots of good examples of this. The older post most likely has higher google priority too. Your not etirely not right but its against the spirit of the entire thing to have 2 uquestions. It happens true, ad your not entirly wrong but dont be surprised if one or the other answer dissapears.

Comment: This is pleasant to the eye to read but to be practical and truthful I don't find this happening especially when I'm searching for UI and functionality related things which is one of the most important things that requires attention after every short period of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering to my own question after two hours of research.

[image]

Make any selected text layer to enter the editing mode is quite simple, just hit

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  (to Edit)

After making changes again hit

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  (to Commit changes)

---

Note: This doesn't work with Previous versions of Photoshop CC 2018 editions.

Comment: Text says ctrl+enter but the animation says ctrl+click... which one is it?

Comment: Apologies - Its Ctrl + Enter, also updated the image with corrected text